# Dynamically add two different layouts to recycler view

Tags: android

I have two layouts 1)for image and 2)for document
 In MainActivity by option menu i select image or pdf from device storage and i send data to adapter class using pojo class.

My problem is that i can not able to bind these layouts properly in recycler view i want to something like when i select image than it will be shown in recycler view and same as pdf file view also in same list.

```
public class HirenModifided extends AppCompatActivity {
    private Dialog dialog;
    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    SetterGetter setGet;

    public static final int RESULT_LOAD_FILE = 0;
    public static final int RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE = 1;
    public static final int RESULT_OK = -1;
    public static final int REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE = 2;
    private ImageAdapter objAdapter;
    public static ArrayList<SetterGetter> pdfPaths = new ArrayList<>();
    public static ArrayList<SetterGetter> imagePaths = new ArrayList<>();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycler);
        setGet = new SetterGetter();

        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        LinearLayoutManager mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext());
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
        objAdapter = new ImageAdapter(getApplicationContext());
        recyclerView.setAdapter(objAdapter);


    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
        return true;
    }

    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.image:
                itemAddClick();
                return true;
            case R.id.file:
                FilePicker();
                return true;
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }

    public void FilePicker() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT);
        intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
        intent.setType("*/*");
        startActivityForResult(intent, RESULT_LOAD_FILE);
    }


    public void itemAddClick() {
        dialog = new Dialog(HirenModifided.this);
        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.custom_dialog_box);
        dialog.setTitle("Select Photo");

        Button btnExit = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.btnExit);
        btnExit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });
        dialog.findViewById(R.id.btnChoosePath).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                activeGallery();
            }
        });
        dialog.findViewById(R.id.btnTakePhoto).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                activeTakePhoto();
            }
        });

        // show dialog on screen
        dialog.show();
    }

    private void activeGallery() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
        startActivityForResult(intent, RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE);
        dialog.dismiss();
    }

    private void activeTakePhoto() {

        Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        dialog.dismiss();

    }


    //this method is for resize image
    public Bitmap getResizedBitmap(Bitmap image, int maxSize) {
        int width = image.getWidth();
        int height = image.getHeight();

        float bitmapRatio = (float) width / (float) height;
        if (bitmapRatio > 1) {
            width = maxSize;
            height = (int) (width / bitmapRatio);
        } else {
            height = maxSize;
            width = (int) (height * bitmapRatio);
        }
        return Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(image, width, height, true);
    }

    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        switch (requestCode) {

            case RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE:
                if (requestCode == RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE &&
                        resultCode == RESULT_OK && null != data) {
                    Uri filePath = data.getData();
                    Log.e("IMAGE", filePath + "");

                    try {
                        InputStream imageStream = this.getContentResolver().openInputStream(filePath);
                        Bitmap selectedImage = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(imageStream);
                        ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                        selectedImage = getResizedBitmap(selectedImage, 400);
                        selectedImage.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);

                        byte[] byteArray = stream.toByteArray();
                       /* setGet.path(Base64.encodeToString(byteArray, Base64.DEFAULT));
                        imagePaths.add(setGet);
                        //FilePaths.clear();
                        FilePaths.addAll(imagePaths);
                        objAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();*/
                        setGet.path(Base64.encodeToString(byteArray, Base64.DEFAULT));
                        imagePaths.add(setGet);
                        objAdapter.insert(imagePaths);


                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                }


            case RESULT_LOAD_FILE:
                if (requestCode == RESULT_LOAD_FILE &&
                        resultCode == RESULT_OK && null != data) {
                    String FilePath = data.getData().getPath();
                    Log.e("FILEPATH", FilePath);
                    String filename = FilePath.substring(FilePath.lastIndexOf("/") + 1);
                    Log.e("onActivityResult: ", filename);

                    /*  setGet.path(filename);
                  pdfPaths.add(setGet);
                    //FilePaths.clear();
                    FilePaths.addAll(pdfPaths);
                    objAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();*/

                    setGet.path(filename);
                    pdfPaths.add(setGet);
                    objAdapter.insert(pdfPaths);
                }
        }


    }


}
```

Pojo

```
public class SetterGetter {
    public static String path;


    public void path(String s) {
        path = s;
    }

    public String getPath() {
        return path;
    }


}
```

Adapter

```
public class ImageAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ImageAdapter.ViewHolder> {
    private LayoutInflater inflater = null;

    public static ArrayList<SetterGetter> file_paths = new ArrayList<>();

    public static final int RESULT_LOAD_FILE = 0;
    public static final int RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE = 1;

    int get_list_position;

    Context context;

    public ImageAdapter(Context mcontext) {
        this.context = mcontext;
        inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    }


    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
        }

    }

    public class FilePick extends ViewHolder {
        TextView temp;

        public FilePick(View v) {
            super(v);
            this.temp = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.file_name);
        }
    }

    public class ImagePick extends ViewHolder {
        ImageView score;

        public ImagePick(View v) {
            super(v);
            this.score = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.image_list);
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onAttachedToRecyclerView(RecyclerView recyclerView) {
        super.onAttachedToRecyclerView(recyclerView);
    }

    // Insert a new item to the RecyclerView on a predefined position
    public void insert(ArrayList<SetterGetter> data) {

        file_paths.add(data.get(get_list_position));
        notifyItemInserted(get_list_position);
    }

   /* // Remove a RecyclerView item containing a specified Data object
    public void remove(SetterGetter data) {
        int position = file_paths.indexOf(data);
        file_paths.remove(position);
        Toast.makeText(context, "Deleted : " + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        notifyItemRemoved(position);
    }*/


    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {

        // Log.e("getItemViewType:pos ", String.valueOf(position));
        Log.e("IS this PDF ?", String.valueOf(file_paths.get(position).getPath().endsWith(".pdf")));
        if (file_paths.get(position).getPath().endsWith("pdf")) {
            return RESULT_LOAD_FILE;
        } else {
            return RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v;

        Log.e("layout code: ", viewType + "");

        if (viewType == RESULT_LOAD_FILE) {
            v = inflater
                    .inflate(R.layout.file_raw, parent, false);
            return new FilePick(v);
        } else {
            v = inflater
                    .inflate(R.layout.raw, parent, false);
            return new ImagePick(v);
        }


    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {


        Log.e("onBindViewHolder:pos ", String.valueOf(position));
        get_list_position = position;

        if (holder instanceof FilePick) {
            FilePick file = (FilePick) holder;
            file.temp.setText(file_paths.get(position).getPath());

        } else if (holder instanceof ImagePick) {
            ImagePick image = (ImagePick) holder;
            byte[] decodeValue = new byte[0];
            try {
                decodeValue = Base64.decode(file_paths.get(position).getPath().getBytes("UTF-8"), Base64.DEFAULT);
            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(decodeValue, 0, decodeValue.length);
            image.score.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return file_paths.size();
    }

}
```

Comment: Your code seems correct, what is the error/problem you're facing ?

Comment: if i select image first time its shows likeE/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                  Process: com.example.guest999.demo_jordar, PID: 10873
                  java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 1, size is 1

Comment: what does   Log.e("onBindViewHolder:pos ", String.valueOf(position)); print?

Comment: when I select image at first time OutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 1, size is 1 , may be i have problem at to maintain view position of on createViewHolder.,

Comment: your log says that Data has only 1 item in it and your `onBindViewHolder` is trying to access position 1 while it should ask for position 0 only. and please edit your question with above problem.

Comment: Log.e("onBindViewHolder:pos ", String.valueOf(position)) it will show the position of recycler view like 0,1,2.....

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/125063/discussion-between-pr38y-and-hiren).

Comment: Thx for suggestion it solved my one problem

Answer (score 0):

add one more variable in your pojo which tells you that which layout will be implemented.

Comment: this could be a comment

Comment: Thx for answer, yes i did that also. but currently i can select view type in getItemViewType(int position){using arryalist contents } and i also checked with static values.

Answer (score 0):

changing your onBindViewHolder to

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {


    Log.e("onBindViewHolder:pos ", String.valueOf(position));
    if (holder instanceof FilePick) {
        FilePick file = (FilePick) holder;
        file.temp.setText(Data.get(position).getPath());

    } else if (holder instanceof ImagePick) {
        ImagePick image = (ImagePick) holder;
        byte[] decodeValue = new byte[0];
        try {
            decodeValue = Base64.decode(Data.get(position).getPath().getBytes("UTF-8"), Base64.DEFAULT);
            Log.e("4", decodeValue + "");
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(decodeValue, 0, decodeValue.length);
        image.score.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
    }
}
```

might help you.

Answer (score 0):

Create one adapter, update `Data` variable when user select anything and call `notifyDataSetChanged` method.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private Dialog dialog;
private RecyclerView recyclerView;
ImageAdapter objImageAdapter;
ArrayList<SetterGetter> FilePaths;
ArrayList<SetterGetter> imagePaths;
ArrayList<SetterGetter> pdfPaths;
SetterGetter setGet;

public static final int RESULT_LOAD_FILE = 0;
public static final int RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE = 1;
public static final int RESULT_OK = -1;
public static final int REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE = 2;
private ImageAdapter objAdapter;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycler);
    setGet = new SetterGetter();
    FilePaths = new ArrayList<SetterGetter>();
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);

                    objAdapter = new ImageAdapter(getApplicationContext(), FilePaths);
                    recyclerView.setAdapter(objAdapter);

}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
    return true;
}

public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.image:
            itemAddClick();
            return true;
        case R.id.file:
            FilePicker();
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}

public void FilePicker() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT);
    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
    intent.setType("*/*");
    startActivityForResult(intent, RESULT_LOAD_FILE);
}


public void itemAddClick() {
    dialog = new Dialog(MainActivity.this);
    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.custom_dialog_box);
    dialog.setTitle("Select Photo");

    Button btnExit = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.btnExit);
    btnExit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    });
    dialog.findViewById(R.id.btnChoosePath).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            activeGallery();
        }
    });
    dialog.findViewById(R.id.btnTakePhoto).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            activeTakePhoto();
        }
    });

    // show dialog on screen
    dialog.show();
}

private void activeGallery() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
    startActivityForResult(intent, RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE);
    dialog.dismiss();
}

private void activeTakePhoto() {

    Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    dialog.dismiss();

}

//Read Shared Images

//this method is for resize image
public Bitmap getResizedBitmap(Bitmap image, int maxSize) {
    int width = image.getWidth();
    int height = image.getHeight();

    float bitmapRatio = (float) width / (float) height;
    if (bitmapRatio > 1) {
        width = maxSize;
        height = (int) (width / bitmapRatio);
    } else {
        height = maxSize;
        width = (int) (height * bitmapRatio);
    }
    return Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(image, width, height, true);
}

public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    switch (requestCode) {

        case RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE:
            if (requestCode == RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE &&
                    resultCode == RESULT_OK && null != data) {
                Uri filePath = data.getData();
                Log.e("IMAGE", filePath + "");

                try {
                    InputStream imageStream = this.getContentResolver().openInputStream(filePath);
                    Bitmap selectedImage = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(imageStream);
                    ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                    selectedImage = getResizedBitmap(selectedImage, 400);
                    selectedImage.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);

                    byte[] byteArray = stream.toByteArray();
                    setGet.path(Base64.encodeToString(byteArray, Base64.DEFAULT));
                    imagePaths.add(setGet);
                    //Log.e("IMAGE",FilePaths+"");
                    FilePaths.clear();
                    FilePaths.addAll(imagePaths);
                    objAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();





                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }


        case RESULT_LOAD_FILE:
            if (requestCode == RESULT_LOAD_FILE &&
                    resultCode == RESULT_OK && null != data) {
                String FilePath = data.getData().getPath();
                Log.e("FILEPATH", FilePath);
                String filename =               FilePath.substring(FilePath.lastIndexOf("/") + 1);
                Log.e("onActivityResult: ", filename);
                setGet.path(filename);
                FilePaths.add(setGet);
               pdfPaths.add(setGet);
                    //Log.e("IMAGE",FilePaths+"");
                    FilePaths.clear();
                    FilePaths.addAll(pdfPaths);
                    objAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

            }
    }
}
}
```